# How to install intel graphics driver for using vulkan on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, intel, vulkan

Environment:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The machine uses Intel iris Pro Graphics 580 (Skylake GT4e) graphics processor.

Vulkan: 1.0.21.1

The problem, I installed the Vulkan 1.x SDK, and try to run the cube example. The error message I got is:

```
./cube
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties failed to find the VK_KHR_surface extension.

Do you have a compatible Vulkan installable client driver (ICD) installed?
Please look at the Getting Started guide for additional information.
```

After I installed mesa-util I had following error message:

```
FINISHME: Get correct values for VkPhysicalDeviceLimits
vulkan: No DRI3 support
Could not find a graphics and a present queue
```

Solutions I tried:

1. https://gist.github.com/SaschaWillems/47be6970a3e99a3d30e1 (I used the Mesa 12.01 instead of Mesa master but I think 12.01 is good enough.)
2. https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/vulkan Still unable to run the cube example after the package is installed.

Any idea about how to get vulkan runs on Intel GPU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran in to the same issue, recently. After following the two steps you mentioned, this last step allowed me to run the cube demo, although I have no idea if it has any power or performance repercussions.

- Version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Graphics card: Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) (system76 lemur)

According to the [Vulkan Setup tutorial](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/app/docs/v1.0.3.1/getting_started_linux), DRI3 stands for 'Direct Rendering Infrastructure 3; a Linux X-Windows extension for direct rendering'

I was able to enable it by following [this ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740977/how-is-dri3-enabled-for-intel-drivers-running-on-a-haswell-igpu-in-ubuntu-15-10) 
 and adding the following lines to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (the file didn't exist on my machine but I added it without issue)

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "SwapBuffersWait" "0"
    Option      "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

Then restart your display manager with `sudo service lightdm restart` (or similar if you changed it) and you should be able to run the demos!

Comment: That fixed my problem, I am able to run the cube example now, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Not sure this change or the update I installed this morning after logged out of ubuntu, I was unable to log in back.  Every time I tried to log in, the screen just blink a second then the OS asked me to input usrname/pw again. I tried to use ctrl + alt + F3 to log in shell. Still failed. I have to reinstall the ubuntu again and the development environment. I   give up using linux and installed win10 for vulkan.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't need to change xorg.conf to get Intel Vulkan drivers running on Ubuntu 16.04. I just used the padoka PPA and followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40792607):

> The [padoka PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa) (linked in [Sascha Willems's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40791189)) worked for me as well, on Ubuntu 16.04.
>
> After adding the PPA to apt, I did the following:
>
> 1. `sudo apt upgrade libglapi-mesa libgl1-mesa-dri vulkan-utils`
> 2. For some reason I had to create an extra symlink for the intel driver:
>
>    ```
>    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libvulkan_intel.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so
>    ```

Comment: It would be preferable if you could at least sum up the most important stuff from your link directly in the question.

Comment: @ByteCommander Done.